# adding -er to a verb

Tags: verbs

Can you add -er to any verb to make a real and accepted word? 
...word in question is Yelper.  I realize that it is a hunting tool- but the questioning party insists that it's proper to add -er to the word yelp as in the dog yelped...

Comment: Define "*a real and accepted word*".

Comment: The Scrabble dictionary indicates **no**, to my frustration.  But otherwise, go for it.

Comment: A proper noun used and recognized as part of the English lexicon. I realize it is a morpheme, but is it correct as a stand alone word?   Such as: I will shower.  Am I now a showerer?

Comment: I apologize for errors and typos- my phone is on an autocorrecting binge!

Comment: You can add _-er_ to just about any verb and make an agent noun that will be recognised and understood by just about any native speaker. Whether that makes it a ‘real and accepted word’ is a matter of definition; a perfectly parseable and understandable word that has nonetheless never been used by anyone else before may not count as a ‘word’ to some, though it does count as one to others. (And of course in some cases the existence of an agent noun in _-or_ will block the existence of one in _-er_, though that's purely orthographic—there's no difference in pronunciation.)

Answer (score 2):

The suffix -er is generally used to form nouns especially with words of Germanic origin, and has been used in the past to make playful formations that has entered common language.

***[-er](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=-er&searchmode=none)***: (etymonline)

> - English agent noun ending, corresponding to Latin -or. In native words it represents Old English -ere (Old Northumbrian also -are) "man who has to do with,"***from Proto-Germanic *-ari.***
> - ***Generally used with native Germanic words.*** *In words of Latin origin, verbs derived from past participle stems of Latin ones (including most verbs in -ate) usually take the Latin ending -or, as do Latin verbs that passed through French (such as governor);* but there are many exceptions (eraser, laborer, promoter, deserter; sailor, bachelor), some of which were conformed from Latin to English in late Middle English.

***-er***

> - ***suffix used to make jocular or familiar formations from common or proper names (soccer being one)***, first attested 1860s, English schoolboy slang, "Introduced from Rugby School into Oxford University slang, orig. at University College, in Michaelmas Term, 1875" [OED, with unusual precision].

[Yelper](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yelper):

> - one that yelps; especially :  a yelping dog (M-W)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in many cases adding -er can change a verb into a noun, the noun being the actor of the verb.

The exceptions are on certain words that use other endings: -or,-ar,-est.

act  -> actor

rape -> rapest  (not raper)

I am fine with "yelper". I like it.

Comment: *-ist*, not *-est*.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do it to ANY verb, but certainly a yelper would be "one who yelps" if we can be clear about what a yelp is.  Certainly it could be used in an appropriate sentence.  "It was the black, long-eared dog that was the loudest yelper."